# Inputs in child component won't update when prop is changing in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a shopping list app that is divided to two components as follows:

[image]

I implemented those two components as: ShoppingList and:ItemDetails
There is another component: ListItem that represents one item row (with edit and delete buttons).
ShoppinList maps over an array of ListItems.

My App component fetches an initial items array and sends it to ShoppingList.
Each time a click is made on the edit icon in a specific item row I set selectedItem object in my app component and render the ItemDetails component, passing it the selectedItem like so:

```
toggleDetailsPanel = (itemId) => (e) => {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
        return {
            selectedItem: (prevState.selectedItem && prevState.selectedItem.id === itemId) ? null : this.findItemById(itemId),
        };
    });
};
```

And in the App render function I render it like that:

```
<div className={styles.details_outer_container}>
                    {this.state.selectedItem ? <ItemDetails handleSubmit={this.saveDetails} item={this.state.selectedItem}/> : null}
                </div>
```

Whenever a click is made on the save button I run a function on the app component that updates the item in the items array (saveDetails).

Now I expected the ItemDetails component to render with new values each time I click on a different edit icon in a different item row, but the inputs values won't change, only the title is rendering.

I tried all solutions that I found, involving defaultValue, or setting value with getValue() function, or setting a dynamic key on the inputs, but nothing really helps.

This is my ItemDetails file:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Grid, Row, Col, input, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styles from './styles.css';

export default class ProductDetails extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        item: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    };

    state = {
        id: this.props.item.id,
        name: this.props.item.name,
        quantity: this.props.item.quantity,
        price: this.props.item.price,
        description: this.props.item.description,
    };

    // Set appropriate property in state by input name
    handleInputChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
    };

    // Submit changed item to parent component
    handleDetailsSubmit = (e) => {
        this.props.handleSubmit(this.state);
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    render() {
        const item = this.props.item;
        const itemName = item.name.toUpperCase() || '';

        return (
            <div className={styles.details_container}>
                <div className="sub_header">
                    <span>{`${itemName} DETAILS`}</span>
                </div>
                <form className={styles.form_style}>
                    <p>
                        <label>{'Quantity'}</label>
                        <input type="text" ref="quantity" name="quantity" value={this.state.quantity}  onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label>{'Price'}</label>
                        <input type="text" ref="price" name="price" value={this.state.price} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label>{'Description'}</label>
                        <textarea rows={2} ref="description" name="description" value={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                    </p>
                    <div className={styles.button_div}>
                        <Button onClick={this.handleDetailsSubmit} bsStyle="primary" bsSize="small">
                            {'Save'}
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </`enter code here`div>

        );
    }

}
```

I understand this is React's way of handling forms but really don't know how to solve it.
I would really appreciate any help : )

Comment: does the value of `this.state.selectedItem` change in AppComponent?

Comment: Yes, it does. in the toggleDetailsPanel  function I pasted here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProductDetails` component only gets its initial values from `item`. From that point it is all maintained in state. So you need to reset the state when `item` changes.

Try adding something like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps( newProps ) {
  if ( this.props.item !== newProps.item ) {
    this.setState( {
      id: newProps.item.id,
      name: newProps.item.name,
      quantity: newProps.item.quantity,
      price: newProps.item.price,
      description: newProps.item.description,
    } )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. But I thought a change in child's prop is supposed to cause re-render and  so the state would be re-initialized through the "state = { ... } initial setting. So I was wrong?

Comment: You are not entirely wrong. Re-render means running the `render` method again, so if you use props inside the render method it will respond to changes. Your state's initial value is being set in the class itself, or inside the `constructor` method, which runs once, when you instantiate the class (by running `new SomeClass()`)

Comment: Ah yeah, I get it. So wouldn’t binding the inputs values to the component’s props be a better solution?

Comment: You could also do that. But you would probably have to change the save method. So I wouldn't say it is better, just a different approach.

Comment: Why would I have to change the save method? in all the inputs onChange method I'm updating the corresponding property in the state, And when saving I'm sending the state object which is up to date with the inputs. So I think binding the inputs to props might be better. But I'm not sure it's the best practice.

Comment: What happens if the user changes the data on an item, but doesn't save it? I don't know your UI, but if they can get out of the edit screen without saving, I think your local data could get messed up. With the current approach, all changes are maintained in the local state of the component so if you browse away without saving, your data is still in sync with the server. But by all means, if updating the data directly on the parent suits your application, go for it, it is not bad practice.

Comment: Well, My App component holds the items array and pass each item to the itemDetails component when selecting a different item. So actually that would fit my app, because I want the data to persist without saving. But I just tried changing the binding of the inputs to "this.props.item.quantity ...etc and like this I cant even type in the inputs, because each typing causes a re render with the default item passed in the first place. Why is that happening? because props are so called "changing" when I type?